# iOS, size of images for background

Tags: ios, image, background

I'm making my first iphone game using swift/xcode with gimp to draw the graphics. I'm having trouble understanding what size I should make the image in gimp to use it for the background of my iphone game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various devices have different screen sizes, so presumably you will want your image to adapt. Thus it really isn't about your image but about the image view that will display it (assuming you're using an image view). The things to think about are:

- How to use constraints to pin the edges of the UIImageView to the edges of the screen.
- How to set the content mode of the UIImageView so that it displays the image acceptably on all device sizes.

Comment: What would be a good image size to start with for the background then? and where could I find more imforamtion about those things? Thank you.

Comment: It depends what you want to do. Does your image have important borders?  Is it okay if it is squeezed and scaled? If so, do you need to preserve the border size (i.e. a resizable image)? Or is it sufficient to show only its center on a smaller device? It all depends on your image and your desires. Experiment with different UIImageView content modes and different device sizes and see what you like.

Comment: The only advice I can give you about size is: as big as the biggest screen size / resolution you intend to run on. The thing you don't want to do is scale _up_ — unless, of course, this is a resizable (i.e. stretchable or tileable) image.

Comment: This seems likes its impossible. If you have a nice background image thats got content that won't look right resized then how do you make it compatable to work with all iPhones?

Comment: Make different versions for different devices, I suppose. The Asset Catalog will help you use the right version on the right device. Make an image set and you'll see what your options are.

Comment: Thanks man I guess ill just play around with it until i figure it out!